# Swift Memory Management for Recursive Protocols

Tags: swift, recursion, memory-management, memory-leaks

Consider the following Class in swift that maintains a recursive relationship with itself

```
class OctupPromisable {

    var promise: OctupPromisable?

    weak var chainedPromise: OctupPromisable?

    func then(octupPromisable: OctupPromisable) -> OctupPromisable? {
        self.promise = octupPromisable
        octupPromisable.chainedPromise = self
        return self.promise
    }

    func start() {
        if nil == self.chainedPromise {
            self.fire(nil)
        }else {
            self.chainedPromise!.start()
        }
    }
}
```

used as such:

```
OctupPromisable()
.then(OctupPromisable())
.then(OctupPromisable())
.start()
```

when I call start with the chainedPromise being weak, it always results in the chainedPromise being nil and hence the start method never recurses.

Making the chainedPromise strong, causes the start method to recurse and work correctly. But in doing so am I not creating a strong cyclic relationship that leads to memory leak? If so, what can be done in order to achieve the recursion and yet avoid memory leak?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make your chained process strong, but after you've used it, set it to `nil`. You're done with it, so you don't need to hold a strong reference any more. If there are no other strong references, the object will be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep references after execution, you could use a strong reference and release inner promises recursively, so when your first promise deallocate, it will not cause a memory leak.

I couldn't test the code but it goes like this:

```
class OctupPromisable {

  weak var promise: OctupPromisable? // Make it weak to avoid reference cycle
  var chainedPromise: OctupPromisable? // Make it a strong reference
  func start() {
    if nil == self.chainedPromise {
      self.fire(nil)
    } else {
      self.chainedPromise!.start()
      self.chainedPromise = nil // Will be deallocated after all 'start' calls 
    }
  }
}
```